Event-click React17 vs Event-click React18
If somebody knows please explain why does events in React18 work exactly like this?

I`v got component custom Select that should open its ul when click on it.To be more precise, when you click on select, the state changes to "isOpen=true" and ul is rendering

const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState(false);

const handleSelectButtonClick = () => {
  setIsOpened(true);
};


I`v got useEffect inside Select. His job - is to add click eventListener on document when isOpen=true. When the next click happens handler have to setIsOpened(false) and ul will be hidden

useEffect(() => {
    const closeByClick = () => {
      setIsOpened(false);
    };

    if (isOpened) {
      document.addEventListener('click', closeByClick);
    }

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', closeByClick);
    }
  }, [setIsOpened, isOpened]);

In React17 logic works as expected:
click  -- setState(true)
--Then re-rendering
--Then useEffect hangs document.addEventListener('click', closeByClick )
In result I see my ul is opened. That`s ok
In React18 logic works a little strange:
click -- setState(true)
--then re-rendering
--then useEffect hangs document.addEventListener('click', closeByClick )
--then!!! handle "closeByClick" is activated and invoke setIsOpened(false), that immediately closes my ul.
---> So one click on Select opened and then closed my ul
I cant understand why did it happen
As if the click-event is bubbled with some delay and reached "document" after! addEventListner() was added on document inside useEffect
PS if add event.stopPropogation() in handleSelectButtonClick, logic again become as expected (in React17 logic works without event.stopPropogation() )
Please if somebody know,  explain me why this happens in react18

This is because of Changes introduced in React 18. Concurrent Rendering and Automatic Batching of State updates. As events click are now processed Asynchronously. Please keep in mind that before React 18  they were not handled like this. This is the primary reason you are experience such kind of behaviour. I would suggest you to visit the following link to understand the behavioural changes.
https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18
https://medium.com/@omrisa25/react-18-what-developers-need-to-know-before-upgrading-e703c9dc2010
Hopefully this will give you clear understanding of the issue at hand.

it still looks like bag in React18. I make a click, after that at least two another asynchronous events occur (setState and useEffect - are asynchronous).
So after click:

assigning setIsOpened(true). Then re-rendering --> all DOM elements starts rendering
running useEffect  --> document.addEventListener('click')
So we have two!! asynchronous events that occurred after we made first click

And only after that our click-event bubbles to the 
Isn`t that strange ?
